# What is idea behind calling calling global operator delete from member operator delete?

Tags: c++, c++11, delete-operator

In Qt's ExternalRefCountData (part of QSharedPtr implementation) https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qsharedpointer_impl.h.html#159

I found code:

```cpp
  inline void operator delete(void *ptr) { ::operator delete(ptr); }
```

What is purpose of this code?

I suppose without this line the things would be the same:

```
auto *d = new ExternalRefCountData;
delete d;//(2)
```

without `ExternalRefCountData::operator delete` line (2) should
call `::operator delete(ptr);` directly, so `ExternalRefCountData::operator delete` is useless?
Or I missed something?

Comment: The reason for adding it was to partially revert another commit that removed that operator, otherwise ASAN complained about mismatched new/delete. Unfortunately, the import to github doesn't reveal the original reason for adding it. It's was added together with the very interesting `inline void operator delete(void *, void *) { }`.

Comment: ... and cppreference says _"The standard library placement forms of operator `delete` (13,14) cannot be replaced and can only be customized if the placement new-expression did not use the `::new` syntax, by providing a class-specific placement delete (25,26) with matching signature: `void T::operator delete(void*, void*)`"_ so perhaps they work in tandem somehow.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  There's no `operator new` overload. Why would a mismatch be detected by removing them?! Mismatch is happening now.

Comment: @Red.Wave _"There's no `operator new` overload"_ - No, there's a class-specific placement `delete`. I can't answer for the mismatch ASAN detected. I just took the text from the commit message.

Comment: @TedLyngmo IIRC the multi-argument `operator delete` is called to clean up in cases where `operator new` fails due to an exception being thrown. In the case of placement new, no cleanup is needed.

Comment: @user253751 That sounds interesting. Any chance that'll only work if the class specific `operator delete` OP asks about is also defined? If so, that could be the answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it should be a bug in the sanitizer then.

Comment: @Red.Wave Could be. I guess one would have to dive into Qts asan enabled tests to dig deeper into the cause and perhaps write a bugreport on asan.